How do I replace all numbers with something other than a number, using Python and regular expressions?
Suppose that we want to replace all integers (0, 1, 2, 3, ...) with a new-line character \n.
How would we do that?
Input: "1 apple 2 orange 3 kiwi"
Output: "\n apple \n orange \n kiwi"

There have been many questions on the topic of matching numbers with regex already. What does this add on top of those?

The following gets the job done:
import re

old_text = "1 apple 2 orange 3 kiwi"

new_text = re.sub("[0-9]", "\n", old_text)

print(repr(new_text))

